# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter doesn't work and doesn't set data to RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

In short, I have a Firebase database which I have connected with my project. I'm retrieving the data from this Firebase database and then I put it to `TableRow` where I have a `RecyclerView`, but at the end it's not displayed on the page.

Here's the proof that I can retrieve the data successfully from Firebase

[image]

[image]

I noticed that my two methods(onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder) at FirebaseRecyclerAdapter don't work, I mean that any `Log.d(TAG, message)` just don't show up in Logcat.

I don't know what might cause this and I'm stuck with this.

What am I doing wrong here, I'm new to Kotlin and Android and I hope to get any helpful tips from you. Feel free to ask anything.

MajorFragment.kt

```
class MajorFragment : Fragment() {

    internal var items: MutableList<Major> = ArrayList()
    internal lateinit var adapter: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Major, MajorViewHolder>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_majors, container, false)
        val recyclerView = root.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_data_majors)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        retrieveData()
        setData(recyclerView)
        return root
    }


    private fun setData(rec_view: RecyclerView) {
        val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Majors")
        val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Major>()
            .setQuery(query, Major::class.java)
            .build()
        Log.d("options", options.toString())
        adapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Major, MajorViewHolder>(options) {

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MajorViewHolder {
                Log.d("onCreateViewHolder", "onCreateViewHolder") // doesnt show in Logcat
                val majorView = LayoutInflater
                    .from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_tablerow, parent, false)
                return MajorViewHolder(majorView, viewType == 1)
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MajorViewHolder, positon: Int, model: Major) {
                holder.setIsRecyclable(true)
                holder.majorTV.text = model.title
                holder.freePlacesTV.text = model.free_places
                holder.kvotasTV.text = model.kvota
                holder.paidPlacesTV.text = model.paid_places
                holder.first_exam.text = model.first_sub
                holder.second_exam.text = model.sec_sub
                holder.third_exam.text = model.third_sub
                holder.min_points_first.text = model.first_sub_points
                holder.min_points_second.text = model.sec_sub_points
                holder.min_points_third.text = model.third_sub_points
                Log.d("Major", ""+holder.majorTV.text) // doesnt show in Logcat
            }
        }
        rec_view.adapter = adapter
        Log.d("adapter", rec_view.adapter.toString())
    }

    private fun retrieveData() {
        items.clear()

        val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .reference
            .child("Majors")

        db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("ERROR", "" + error.message)
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for(majorSnapShot in snapshot.children)
                {
                    val major = majorSnapShot.getValue(Major::class.java)
                    items.add(major!!)
                    Log.d("Majors", ""+items.size)
                }
            }
        })
    }

      override fun onStart() {
         if(adapter != null)
         adapter.startListening()
         super.onStart()
      }

      override fun onStop() {
          if(adapter != null)
          adapter.stopListening()
          super.onStop()
      }
    }
```

fragment_majors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".ui.majors.MajorsFragment"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow android:background="#5F8A96" >

            <TextView
                just a TextView />
            <TextView
                just a TextView />
            <TextView
                just a TextView />
            <TextView
                just a TextView />
            <TextView
                just a TextView />
            <TextView
                just a TextView />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:background="#F0F7F7" >
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_data_majors"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

layout_tablerow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:background="#F0F7F7"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/majorsTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/style_border_table"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Математика" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/freePlacesTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/style_border_table"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="20" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/kvotasTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/style_border_table"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/paidPlacesTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/style_border_table"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="6" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/exams"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/style_border_table"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_exam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Мат"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_exam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Инф"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/third_exam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Рус"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/min_points"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/style_border_table"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/min_points_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="39"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/min_points_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="44"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/min_points_third"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="45"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

So, I found what caused my recyclerView not to work. Basically it was because of my `layout_tablerow.xml`. Well see, I had `ScroolView` in that file, I didn't show it the question cause I thought it wasn't important.

All other files were working fine. So if you are using `RecyclerView` with `ScroolView` you will not get any data displayed.
I hope it helped you.